# Access a Meteor App's unique .id

Tags: meteor

I'm writing a Meteor package that needs to know the id of the app that includes it -- the value that is saved in the `.meteor/.id` file relative to the project directory.

How can I access the id safely in development AND in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Meteor 1.2.1, (and 1.3) the appId is accessible via the `__meteor_runtime_config__.appId` variable on the client and server in development mode. This is undocumented so we don't know if it will be available in future versions.

The `.appId` property of `__meteor_runtime_config__` is **NOT** available:

- In production mode (when `Meteor.isProduction`)
- In test mode (when `Meteor.isTest`)
- In app test mode (when `Meteor.isAppTest`)

Comment: In Meteor 1.4+ the `appId` is available via `__meteor_runtime_config__.appId` even in production mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable from server-side code using NPM. I just tested the following on my local project and it works:

```
// server-side code

// FYI, Npm.require works in packages only. Use meteorhacks:npm to use 
// in non-package code. In meteor shell you can just use `require`.
var fs = Npm.require('fs'); 
var path = Npm.require('path');

var idPath = path.join(process.env.PWD, '.meteor/.id');
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(idPath);
var fileContentLines = fileContent.toString().split('\n');

// this will contain the ID
var theId = fileContentLines[fileContentLines.length - 2];
```

Now, keep in mind that in **production**, you don't have the `.meteor` directory. After running a `grep` for the id in the build folder, it seems to me like that ID is not stored in any file within the build. Therefore, you will need to create a build plugin which makes sure to make it accessible somewhere during the build process. I may not have looked hard enough, so I would definitely take a look at the source for the build tool and see what it does with that ID during build.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Meteor Settings file http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings? It should be the right way to do that, Otherwise you will have to use Node.js to access the file directly